# Angle definition for $\text{SO}(3)$ matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, rotations, isometry, orthogonal-matrices

My goal is to prove that a matrix in $\text{SO}(3)- \{I\}$ is completely determined by its angle of rotation and its axis.

Suppose $A\in \text{SO}(3)$ and let $f$ be the unique linear operator associated to. Then if $A$ is not the identity there's a unique one dimensional subspace $a$ of $\mathbb{R}^3$ such that $v \in a \implies Av=v$.

$a$ is defined to be the axis of rotation.

Now since $a$ is unique given $A\neq I$ so is $a^\perp$, and both are $f$-invariant subspaces. From here how do I define the angle of rotation $\theta$?

Here's a possible approach.

Define the restriction $f'$ of $f$: $f':a^\perp \rightarrow a^\perp$. Since $f$ is associated to an orthogonal matrix it is an isometry, and so is $f'$. Being $f'$ the restriction of a linear map it is also linear. Furthermore $\det(f)=\det(f')=1$ because of the following reasoning:

pick a unitary $v\in a$, and complete $v$ to $\{v,w,u\}$, an orthonormal basis of $\mathbb{R}^3$. The matrix $P$ of change of basis is orthogonal, and $B=P^{-1}AP$, the matrix of $f$ w.r.t. $\{v,w,u\}$, is still orthogonal. It will be of the form $\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0\\ 
0 & M
\end{pmatrix}$. Now $B^TB=I$, so $M^TM=I$, and $\det(f')=\det(M)=\det(B)=\det(A)=\det(f)=1$.

So $f'$ is a rotation on the plane, hence it is associated with a unique angle, and so is $A$, **if an orientation of the plane $a^\perp$ is given**.

Indeed, $M\in \text{SO}(2)$, so $M=\begin{pmatrix}
\cos(\theta) & \sin(\theta)\\ 
-\sin(\theta) & \cos(\theta)
\end{pmatrix}$. This determines a unique angle $\theta$. How can I be sure this angle doesn't depend on the choice of $\{v,w,u\}$? For sure its magnitude is 'fixed', since $2\cos(\theta)=\text{tr}(M)=-1+\text{tr}(B)=-1+\text{tr}(A)$, so it is invariant under change of basis.

What about the sign? If I chose as a basis $\{v,u,w\}$ instead of $\{v,w,u\}$ then $M$ would still be in $\text{SO}(2)$ by the above result, its trace would be the same, so the only option would be $\begin{pmatrix}
\cos(\theta) & -\sin(\theta)\\ 
\sin(\theta) & \cos(\theta)
\end{pmatrix}$, corresponding to $-\theta$.

Will define the angle in $(-\pi, \pi]$ solve the problem?

Is it false that a matrix in $\text{SO}(3)- \{I\}$ is completely determined by its angle of rotation and its axis? I could easily prove my statement If I was given the axis with an orientation...

Comment: I gave an answer already, but I'd like to add that I really like this question a lot. It would have been so easy to say "take a rotation, compute its axis as a vector $v$, extend $v$ to an oriented basis of 3-space, and determine the rotation angle in the orthogonal plane" (as so many folks have tried to do). But you instead recognized that the axis had to be *unoriented*, and pushed on to a far more interesting question. Thanks for getting me to think about this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's true that an axis and angle (together with an orientation of 3-space) determine a unique rotation matrix; Rodrigues' formula provides the mapping from $S^2 \times \Bbb R \to SO(3)$.

It's not true that an element of $SO(3)$ (or, equivalently, a rotation of 3-space, together with an orientation of 3-space) provide a unique axis and angle, at least not if we want the axis to be in $S^2$. But you've at least partly resolved this by saying that the axis is in $\Bbb RP^2$, which is a good choice: a 90 degree rotation about the $z$-axis is also a rotation about the $-z$ axis (so to speak), but in $RP^2$, these are the same "axis".

The problem is that the 90 degree rotation about $z$ is a $-90$ degree rotation about $-z$. So which angle do you use? You've bumped up against this problem, and have seen that it's a problem, but let me ramble on a bit. Let's name a function based on Rodrigues' formula:
$$
F: S^2 \times \Bbb R \to SO(3)
$$
takes an axis-angle pair to a rotation matrix. There's an action of $G = \Bbb Z / 2 \Bbb Z = \{e,a\}$ on the domain, namely 
$$
e(v, \theta) = (-v, \theta)
$$
The quotient of the domain by this action is $\Bbb RP^2 \times \Bbb R$, and you're hoping that $F$ has an inverse when we look at this "quotient domain."

The problem is that $F$ doesn't "pass to the quotient", i.e., it's *not* true that 
$$
F( a \cdot (v, \theta)) = F(v, \theta),
$$
in general. So hoping for an inverse in this quotient domain is hopeless.

However there *is* another action of $G$ on the domain, namely
$$
a \cdot (v, \theta) = (-v, -\theta),
$$
and with *this* action, $F$ *does* pass to the quotient: 
$$
F(v, \theta) = F(-v, -\theta)
$$
Furthermore, if we remove $I$ from the codomain, and restrict the domain to be 
$$
S^2 \times ( [-\pi, 0) \cup (0, \pi] ),
$$
then $F$, after passing to the quotient, is actually $1-1$ and onto, so it has an inverse. That means that you can associate, to any rotation, an element of the quotient, i.e. a pair of the form
$$
\{ (v, \theta), (-v, \theta) \}
$$
where $v \in S^2$.

Now you could say "OK, great. I'm gonna select from that pair the one for which the rotation angle is *positive*" and that will actually work...but it *won't* give a continuous function, which may turn out to be important to you.

I'm not sure whether this addresses your question, but I hope it's at least of some value.

Comment: Just idle curiosity, so feel free to neglect this comment, but is the issue here ultimately going to come down to the fact that $SO(3)$ isn't simply connected? Would it be true that we could uniquely specify an element of $Spin(3)$ by its axis and angle of rotation?

Comment: Well...certainly the 2-torsion in $\pi_1 SO(3)$ is always troublesome (or fascinating, depending on your viewpoint, I guess). To be honest, back when I should have been paying attention 40 years or so ago, I kinda tuned out during discussion of $Spin(n)$, and have never had occasion to go back and study up on it, so you could well be right, but I wouldn't be the one to know. :)

Comment: I think I'm wrong. I just always think of $Spin(n)$ whenever the fact that $SO(n)$ is poorly behaved comes up. I think the real issue here is that we want $SO(3)$ to be covered by $S^2 \times S^1$ ($S^2$ is the set of rotation axes and $S^1$ is the set of angles). But in fact, $SO(3)$ only has $Spin(3)$ as a nontrivial cover, which is isomorphic to $SU(2)$, which is isomorphic to $S^3$. The trouble arises when we try to think of $S^3$ as $S^2 \times S^1$, which are not even homotopy equivalent to each other.

Comment: Exactly right, I believe. There really is a natural desire to think that everything can be decomposed as a product of things we already understand, and "twisted products" (e.g., bundles) just mess with our heads, despite our best intentions.

Comment: You saying "twisted products" has me thinking "something something Hopf fibration." Maybe that's the key to *really* understanding this problem.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, and thanks a lot for your answer, which is unfortunately too advanced in some parts for me to follow.. However I understand that according to you an axis is a unitary vector (as in Rodrigues formula). So you said: when an orientation of the space is given, any $\text{SO}(3)$ matrix is determined by one unitary vector and one angle, or in different words, given a unitary vector and an angle (and an orientation of the space) a unique $\text{SO}(3)$ matrix is determined. Did I get this right? One cannot take away some ingredients otherwise ambiguity arises, correct?

Comment: Yes: Rodrigues tells you how to take a unit vector and an angle and produce an element $R(u, \theta) \in SO(3)$. The problem comes in *inverting* this operation, even on $SO(3) - \{I\}$: the inverse operation, applied to $R(u, \theta)$ can give you either $a = (u, \theta)$ or $b = (-u, -\theta)$ (even if you limit $\theta$ to $[-\pi, \pi]$). By picking whichever of $a$ and $b$ has a *positive* angle, you get a single vector-angle pair, but the vector does not vary continuously as a function of the matrix entries, which may cause problems in some applications.